# opencv search for a single haar feature

Tags: opencv

How can I manually create a single haar feature and search for it within an image?

The plan was to find everything that matches a haar feature like this:
[image: haar]

And then approximate a line across all the found ones.
What I want to avoid is rewriting the algorithm of integral images myself.

The task is to detect an (almost) straight line
(on a very noisy image where a canny + findEdges result in million lines)

Not sure if it's the right way, and so far the best idea I have.
Plus, how do I handle different image sizes for the haar? I don't want to resize the image to 20x20, when all the fine details are lost.

[image]

Comment: Maybe someone can assist with an cascade.xml that contains only a single feature ?

Comment: is that haar feature really what you are looking for? I'm not that experienced with haar features, but I would expect that the white areas should be about as big as the black area. In your example, the white area is much smaller around a big black area...

Comment: I was planing use multiple 'handcrafted` features later on, but, presumably, for the straight line detection this one with slight modifications should do